# update stripe information into magento 2.3 orders using rest api

Tags: magento2.3, payment, rest-api, stripe

I am creating an order using rest API in Magento 2.3, Order created using cash on delivery payment method.

In my scenario need to create an order using stripe payment gateway method.

Cash on delivery payment method payload:

```
"payment": {
            "method": "cashondelivery",
            "amount_paid":100
        },
```

My Question:
1. How to send the stripe token in payment information